# Add a listener/return a future to get http response if channel pool is used

Tags: netty

I want to implement a simple async http client with connection pooling.

This is my connection pool map.

```
channelPool = new AbstractChannelPoolMap<InetSocketAddress, ChannelPool>() {
        @Override
        protected ChannelPool newPool(InetSocketAddress key) {
            Bootstrap bootstrap = getBootstrap().remoteAddress(key);
            return new FixedChannelPool(bootstrap, nett4HttpClientInitializer, maxConnectionsPerHost);
        }
    };
```

And this is netty4HttpClientInitializer

```
public void channelCreated(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) ch;
        channel.config().setKeepAlive(true);
        channel.config().setTcpNoDelay(true);
        if (connectTimeout > 0) {
            channel.config().setConnectTimeoutMillis(connectTimeout);
        }
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
        // Enable HTTPS if necessary.
        if (sslContext != null) {
            pipeline.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(channel.alloc()));
        }
        if (proxy != null) {
            if (proxyUser != null && !proxyUser.trim().isEmpty()) {
                pipeline.addLast(new HttpProxyHandler(proxy, proxyUser, proxyPassword));
            } else {
                pipeline.addLast(new HttpProxyHandler(proxy));
            }
        }
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpContentDecompressor());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(maxResponseSize));
        if (readTimeout > 0) {
            pipeline.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        }}
```

The question is if I add a SimpleChannelInboundHandler to netty4HttpClientInitializer I think it will be shared by every thread which will call pool.acquire().

Could you please help me to make SimpleChannelInboundHandler stateless ?
A listener inside channelRead0 ? Execute a task -channelContext.executor().submit() ?

P.S. I call pool.acquire() from outside of netty event loop. And I want to get a future with HttpResponse.